# What are the performance implications of BeginTransaction() vs BeginTransactionAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have an implementation of an *atomic transaction* in which many contexts are being updated inside an asynchronous HTTP POST method.

Before the transaction implementation, I was manipulating my contexts asynchronously
eg (`await _context.Foo.AddAsync(trade);` `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`)

After understanding the need for transitions and seen many synchronous examples out there I decided to implement them synchronously:

```cs
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //_context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine();

                try
                {
                    _context.Foo.Add(foo);
                    _context.SaveChanges();

                    _context.TradeItems.AddRange(new List<Bar>{});
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    
                    transaction.Commit();
```

Since atomicity is a priority to me, I am OK doing it this way.

However, should I do it async instead? **What are the performance implications of BeginTransaction() vs BeginTransactionAsync()**

Comment: basically, as with any async: while the requested service in the backend works (=creates a transaction), the thread _waiting_ for the result can do other work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Asynchronous function versions are introduced for reusing threads which are "waiting" for operation completion. If your application has a lot of simultaneous requests - asynchronous calls is a benefit.

If you really care about performance and server resources, rewrite your code to use asynchronous versions. And do not call `SaveChanges` after each operation.

```cs
using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    try
    {
        _context.Foo.Add(foo);
        _context.TradeItems.AddRange(new List<Bar>{});

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
```

`AddAsync` is needed only of you have special value generation in your entities which needs Database request.

Comment: +1  For AddAsync & SaveChanges after each operation hints. My understanding of contexts was that each DbSet was a different one, apparently, that's not the case.

Comment: This will implicitly call `transaction.Dispose()`, which is a synchronous blocking operation. Instead use `await using`, which will call `await transaction.DisposeAsync()` instead.

Comment: Somebody is bound to get their knickers in a bunch... but asynchronous calls are orthogonal to multi-threading. In fact, async calls are all about maximizing the utilization of *one* thread by letting it do other work while it waits for I/O operations (primarily) to finish without blocking the thread, NOT about using multiple threads. That the framework *might* sometimes resume an async operation on a different thread than the one it started on is immaterial, and not necessarily undesirable since there are a number of issues that can hamper performance doing that, like CPU cache invalidation.

Comment: I am getting Task<IDBContextTransaction> does not contain a definition for 'CommitAsync' error

Comment: @PeterChikov, for sure `Task` do not have such method. Probably you forgot `await`. `var transaction = await ...`